# Checkbox option for user to delete contents. The feature to delete the row is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I want to display contents of data along with a checkbox option to delete selected row from table. The data is successfully showing along with checkbox option with each row but i am not able to make a successfully working delete feature to delete selected row. Can someone help me o how to fix this.
This is my code to display the data from database

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM files";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($files as $file): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input type = "checkbox" value="<?php $file['id']; ?>" name="checkbox[]"></td>
      <td><?php echo $file['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $file['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo floor($file['size'] / 1000) . ' KB'; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $file['downloads']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="uploads.php?file_id=<?php echo $file['id'] ?>">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

And this is the code i tried to work for deleting selected row

```
<input type="submit" value="DELETE" id="delete" name="delete">

if(isset($_POST["delete"])){
    $check = $_POST["checkbox"];
    foreach($chech as $id){
        mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM files WHERE id=".$id);
    }
}
```

The code to delete the selected checkbox is doing nothing till now.

Comment: `$check !== $chech` <= typo

Comment: Consider whether you really want to allow users to 'hard delete' data this way.